# TypeError: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor

Tags: remix.run, cloudflare-pages

I am trying to run my remix app (with cloudflare pages) locally:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "remix build",
    "dev:remix": "remix watch",
    "dev:wrangler": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run wrangler",
    "dev": "npm-run-all build --parallel \"dev:*\"",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run wrangler",
    "typecheck": "tsc",
    "wrangler": "wrangler pages dev ./public"
}
```

As part of authentication I am using firebase auth via firebase-admin in my app. This seems to be a problem as it's using XMLHttpRequest:

```
[mf:err] TypeError: globalThis.XMLHttpRequest is not a constructor
    at checkTypeSupport (.../functions/[[path]].js:16068:17)
    at node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/capability.js (.../functions/[[path]].js:16081:177)
    at .../functions/[[path]].js:14:52
    at node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/http-lib/request.js (.../functions/[[path]].js:18191:5)
    at .../functions/[[path]].js:14:52
    at node-modules-polyfills:http (.../functions/[[path]].js:18350:5)
    at .../functions/[[path]].js:14:52
    at node-modules-polyfills-commonjs:http (.../functions/[[path]].js:18450:21)
    at .../functions/[[path]].js:17:47
    at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js (.../functions/[[path]].js:22740:76)
```

The `wrangler.toml` looks like this:

```
compatibility_date = "2023-05-01"
compatibility_flags = ["streams_enable_constructors", "nodejs_compat"]
node_compat = true
```

I tried installing `npm i xmlhttprequest` and setting it globally:

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

That didn't work.